# Need some help on equations (lines, spiral curves and polar curves)

Tags: functions, computer-science, polar-coordinates, parametric, implicit-function

I have some issues with understanding the differences between implicit and explicit equations of lines and spirals. I have tried to do my assignment but found that I am struggling.

Here is my workings for Q1. The rest i'm still very unsure about how to approach it. Would appreciate help. I'm honestly not even sure if i am on the right track for the first question.
[Questions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISCHL.png)

> y-y1 = m(x-x1)  
>  y-2=[(2-7)/(1-4)] (x-1) 
>   y = 5x/3 + 1/3 
>   and therefore, this is my parametric equation  
>  
>   x= u  
>   y = 5u/3 + 1/3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okay! thank you for your advice